# iPhone popup menu like iPad popover?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, popover

How can i implement this popup menu in iphone app like a popover in ipad?

[image]

---

**EDIT**: This is the best at moment: https://github.com/runway20/PopoverView
[image]

Comment: @Kev You close my question because it's not a real question? After 12439 views? and a lot of comments/answer? It's so strange as question? Maahh.

Comment: In my opinion this is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have a look at the iPhone UIPopoverController implementation: [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if using WEPopover in my app is ok if I want to put it on the Store?

Comment: Should be. I don't know the details since a colleague did the implementation, but we've got a modified version of it in our live app.

Comment: [Suragch's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32295907/4106164) is now the standard way of doing this after iOS 8.

Answer (score 34):

## iOS 8 and later

Beginning with iOS 8, you can use [`UIPopoverPresentationController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html) for iPhones in addition to iPads.

[image]

## Setup

- Add a `UIBarButtonItem` to your main View Controller.
- Add another View Controller to the storyboard. Change it to the size that you want the popover to be and add any content that you want it to have. For my example I just added a `UILabel`. If you want a whole menu, then just add a table view or list of buttons.
- Add a segue from the bar button item to the view controller that you will use as the popover. Rather than `show`, choose `Present as Popover`.

[image]

- Select the segue in the storyboard and set the identifier to `popoverSegue` (or whatever string you called it in the code).

[image]

- In the Attributes inspector for the popover view controller, check **Use Preferred Explicit Size** and confirm that it is the size you want it to be.

[image]

## Code

This is the code for the main view controller that has the bar button item in it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {

            let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController
            popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
            popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self

        }
    }

    // MARK: - UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method

    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {

        // Force popover style
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
    }
}
```

## Popover at an arbitrary anchor point

If you want to set the popover to appear somewhere besides a bar button item (on a `UIButton` for example) then you need to set the `sourceView` and `sourceRect`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38797837/3681880) for details.

[image]

## Further reading

The above example comes mostly from the first link.

- [iPad Style Popovers on the iPhone with Swift](https://richardallen.me/2014/11/28/popovers.html)
- [iOS 8 Popover Presentations](http://rbnsn.me/posts/2014/09/08/ios-8-popover-presentations/)
- [UIPopoverPresentationController on iOS 8 iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319179/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-on-ios-8-iphone)
- [General overview of popup options in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32295641/3681880)

Answer (score 19):

On iPhone you would generally use a UIActionSheet for a stack of buttons like that.  It slides up from the bottom, rather than popping up next to the button, but that's the standard behavior on iPhone.

Comment: uhm... how can i implement it? PS: the screenschot above come from iphone app!

Comment: @Paska: which iphone app is this? i'm curious

Comment: @user102008 I don't remember, but is a view with rounded corner and an arrow image! Nothing so easy!

Comment: Ya better to stick with action sheet cos most of the iPhone users have used to it.

Comment: It is worth noting that the Facebook iOS app uses this "popover" style on the iPhone, even though standard UIKit only allows popovers on the iPad.  Given that there are many users of the Facebook app, one can assume that a large number of people will now be quite accustomed to a popover style display on an iPhone

Answer (score 7):

There is one that is even better than WEPopover.  Developed by a company called 50pixels, it is called **FPPopover**.

You can download FPPopover at **https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover**

Comment: This doesn't work with `UIBarButtonItems` (in my limited experience anyway)

Comment: Also has a lot of memory issues logged

Answer (score 5):

You would have to manually instantiate a UIView using a custom background image or drawing with transparency, add some UIButtons (or other type of custom view) on top, and also somehow handle all touches outside that view.

Note that is is non-standard UI.  An actionsheet would be more HIG compliant.

Answer (score 2):

To get a popover from a right side bar button item on a navigation controller that is part of a tableview controller, the following worked for me for **Swift 4** and Xcode 9.

1. Follow the steps in [Suragch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3681880/suragch) answer above (as edited by the Community.)
2. Do not implement the Segue as shown in the answer above.  For some reason, the segue causes the popover to go full screen despite setting the explicit size.
3. Give your popover view controller a title in Attributes Inspector
4. Add the following code in the TableView controller where the popup will show.
5. Modify the string identifier (the one here is referencing a Constant.swift file)
6. Modify "as! FilterVC" to use the title of the your popover view controller.

   ```
   /// Shows a filter popover view
   @IBAction func filterBtnPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
       let popover = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: FILTER_VC) as! FilterVC
       popover.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
       popover.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
       popover.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
       popover.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = ColorPalette.Blue.Medium
       popover.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
       popover.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view!.bounds.width, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
       popover.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
       self.present(popover, animated: true)
   } }


   func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
       return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can check WYPopoverController: https://github.com/sammcewan/WYPopoverController

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot above is not a UIActionSheet. It looks like a simple UIView subclass with custom UIButtons on top of it. So go ahead and create the subclass according to your needs and then add it as a subview to your view every time you need it.