# Make Popups With Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, popup

I'm trying to make a popup like in "Camera+" or "Tweetbot" (like this one : [Tweetbot](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/261/img1125.png) or this one [Camera+](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/1551/img1128.png)). How can I do this ?

Comment: I think you're looking for something that doesn't exist as standard. It looks to me as though those images were made specifically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That component is generally called a Popover or a Callout. Apple provides you with an Implementation on the iPad (UIPopover) but not on the iPhone.

There are a few Libraries which attempts to solve this and creates similar popovers like the ones you've shown. With a bit of customisation you can get it to look like this ones you've linked. Below is a list of the ones i've found so far:

- [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)
- [CMPopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView)
- [PopupView](https://github.com/sonsongithub/PopupView)

Comment: From iOS 8 on, you can use `UIPopoverPresentationController` for iPhones as well as iPads. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32295641/3681880) for some links.

Answer (score 2):

There's similar question here: [iPhone popup menu like iPad popover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769169/iphone-popup-menu-like-ipad-popover).

There is a solution. It's called **WEPopover** and you can [download it from github](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover).

Comment: Do you have a tutorial of how to use WEPopover?

Answer (score 0):

For ipad use the popover control:

http://www.matthewcasey.co.uk/2010/04/07/tutorial-introduction-to-pop-over-control-on-ipad-part-1/

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I'm looking for something that could work for both iPhone and iPad (an iPT of course :P) so …