# How was this 'pop-up' view created?

Tags: iphone, view, ibooks

Please see the image below.

How was this 'pop-up' view created?  Suppose I wanted to completely imitate that view with the fonts, how would I do so?

[image]

Comment: It's just a custom view with several subviews: background UIImageView, three UIButtons, one UILabel and one UISwitch.

Comment: It's simply a Custom View!

Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769169/iphone-popup-menu-like-ipad-popover

easy to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a SDK exposed component for this, but this could very easily be made using a hierarchy of views:

> UIView - Main view.  Uses a bezier path to create a protrusion to
>   point from the source. Has a border and drop shadow added to its
>   layer.
>
> UIButton - Smaller font
>      UIButton - Larger font
>      UIButton - Change font type
>      UIButton - Container for sepia. 
>          UILabel - "Sepia" text
>          UISwitch - turning sepia on and off

Just show and hide the view with an animation.  Also, create delegate callbacks to tell the delegate when events occur in the popover.

```
// Delegate returns if the text can get smaller to enable/disable the button
- (BOOL) didSelectSmallerFont:(CGFloat)fontSize;
// Delegate returns if the text can get larger to enable/disable the button
- (BOOL) didSelectLargerFont:(CGFloat)fontSize; 
- (void) didChangeFont:(UIFont*)font;
- (void) didToggleSepia:(BOOL)enabled;
```

etc.

Comment: Good answer +1, but to be more modern (and assuming you're targeting iOS 4.0+) you should use blocks instead of callbacks.

Comment: @kubi - Exactly what I was thinking while reading this... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The pyramid shape is not associated with the button that was clicked to present the popup. It would be a subview of the popup view, either a UIImageView or possibly drawn on a UIView, although a UIImageView would be the easier solution. You could definitely code the popup view to point that arrow at any point on the screen or in any direction. What I would do is instantiate the popup by means of an init method called `initFromPoint:`, then pass the center value of the button used to launch the popup. Then within the `viewDidLoad` method of the popup place the point appropriately based on the point.