# How to create a popup for the UITableViewCell like in Music App on iPhone (iOS 5)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uikit, popup

Is there a simple way to create a popup like on the follow picture:

[image: Screenshot from Music App]

The popup should only show up while pressing on the UITableViewCell and after releasing the touch event it should disappear. I wanna get the same behavior like on the iOS 5 (iPhone/iPod Touch)

I also checked [WEPopover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4769169/1045625). But I would like to know if there is a native way to do it like apple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On github there is a beautiful project that respond on you question!

Here the code:  https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView

Easy to use.

A