# Is this control available in UIKit?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

I want to create some control which looks like "Select | Select All | Paste"

[image]

I want the control popover when a button tapped.

Is this control implemented in UIKit? How to create one?

Special thanks!

Comment: Do you want that specific control for a text view? Or do you what that *type* of control?

Comment: UIMenuController is a native controller from iOS. You can add your custom controls in the popover.Also, you can control the behavior using notifications and delegate calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `UIMenuController`. It’s slightly weird to use, see [sample code on GitHub](https://github.com/zoul/UILabel-Clipboard-Sample). If you’re after a general popover control, that’s available on the iPad as `UIPopoverController` and on the smaller devices via [many third-party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547969/how-to-create-popover-in-iphone-app) or custom `UIView` subclasses.