# Presenting UIAlertController ActionSheet in popover on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, popover, uialertcontroller

I'm creating and presenting an `ActionSheet` as follows:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
alertController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

// Add some buttons

alertController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = someBarButton

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works fine on the iPad, but `alertController.popoverPresentationController` is `nil` on the iPhone.

I've successfully presented popovers on the iPhone using adaptive segue style **Present As Popover** in interface builder and implementing `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController` delegate method to return the correct `UIModalPresentationStyle` but I'm stuck how to do it in code with `UIAlertController` as it has no `popoverPresentationController` on the iPhone

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, and I may be wrong on this, but I think it's just not possible to show an action sheet in a popover on iPhone, even in iOS 8.

Comment: This link may help you out :)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/25656733/3964913

Comment: @GordonWorswick unfortunately not. Per my question, `UIAlertController` doesn't have a `popoverPresentationController` on the iPhone

Comment: The link below may be useful;http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html

Comment: popover is not possible in Iphone , It is the function only implemented for Ipad , If you still wanted a popover try using a custom popup screen.

Comment: @vinay.bn That is just wrong. Since iOS 8 you can use `UIPopoverPresentationController` to present a popover on an iPhone

Comment: @Ashley Mills: Your approach would be true if your application was supporting iOS 8 and above, By the by the comment was of 8 months back when iOS 9 was not launched , generally application would support previous one version atleast.

Comment: @vinay.bn Irrelevant. Your answer is still wrong. Popovers are possible on the iPhone,  and were possible when the question was asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UIAlertController is not meant to be a popover. There seems to be some controversy about this in the comments. Your code above wouldn't work if it was actually respecting the `.Popover` style. Why? Because it needs to have a `sourceView` and a `sourceRect` set on the popoverPresentationController object to know where to point the arrow. If you swap UIAlertController out for UIViewController it'll crash because those values aren't set. Ironically if you do try force unwrap the popoverPresentationController it'll crash:

```
alertController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
alertController.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = sender // CRASH!!!
alertController.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = sender.bounds
```

For all details on how to implement an iPhone popover (for everything else but UIAlertController) look at my [iPhone Popover blog post](http://koreyhinton.com/blog/iphone-popover.html).

The fact that the popover presentation controller is nil is pretty telling that its not supposed to be a popover.

**Table View Alternative**

You might consider UITableViewController as a replacement here. Using the Grouped style actually looks pretty nice in popovers.

**Picker**

You are going to run into this problem probably over and over again, where you want the user to just select from a few options. I'd suggest you encapsulate whatever user interface control you're going to use into your own picker object. The implementation details of whether its a table view or just a line-up of buttons can be disguised from the calling code and you can have a delegate or closure callbacks when selection at a particular index occurs. Here's roughly what the API might look like:

```
class Picker: UIViewController {
    init(items: [String])
    selectionCompletion: (index: Int, item: String)->Void
}

// Usage:
let picker = Picker(["Answer A","Answer B"])
picker.selectionCompletion = { index, item in
    // handle selection
}
```

This way you can reuse it anywhere you'd like and the API is very simple