# Shift to UIPopoverPresentationController

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uipopovercontroller, uipopover, uipopoverbackgroundview

I want to create the same popover for my iPhone app with size `GGrect` of `(320 100.0)`.
Here is my old code:

```objc
View * pk1 = [[View alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pk1];
pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];
[pop setDelegate:self];
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:[self btnsavepart].frame inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
[nav release];
```

I using this codes but its doesn't change

```
nav.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 100);
```

I can not change `UIpopovercontriller` with `UIPopoverPresentationController`.

How do I specify `GGrect` of `(320 100.0)`?

i thinks i can change only on  horizontally but how can i do.

```
  View *viewController = [[[View alloc] init] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController] autorelease];


    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    navController.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
    navController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = btnsavepart.bounds;
    navController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = btnsavepart;
    navController.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

i want the  UIPopoverPresentationController not FullScreen form in iPhone

i adding this codes but i give the FullScreen view

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller
```

{

```
return NO;
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIPopoverPresentationController on iOS 8 iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319179/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-on-ios-8-iphone)

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate because of *"I can not change UIpopovercontriller with UIPopoverPresentationController"*.

Comment: @jww Why does that make a difference? The OP in this question is trying to use `UIPopoverPresentationController` to present a popover in this question, just like in the duplicated question.

Comment: first its not duplicate and please give me the solution if you have

Comment: HI @user2296278 didi you find the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I work with Xamarin but its same thing , to specify size of the popover in which you want to display your UIViewController, in the properties of your UIVIewController you have the PreferredContentSize property. There you specify the size.

I saw it somewhere here but forgot where.