# Present Popover iOS 8 storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, popover, xcode-storyboard

I am making an iOS 8 app, and I like to use the storyboard whenever possible.
My problem is very simple, I want to make a simple popover view that appears when a user clicks a button entirely from storyboard! 
When the user taps on "ADD" the popover is displayed.

So I did that:

[image: a screenshot]

It works on iPad:
[image: texte]

but on iPhones (anyone) it displays the popover on fullscreen. 
[image: another screenshots]

But I thought that the new popover system works on iOS 8  (my deployment Target is iOS 8)

Someone knows why?
Thank you in advance.
And sorry for my English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIPopoverPresentationController on iOS 8 iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319179/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-on-ios-8-iphone)

Comment: pop over on iPad & iPhone & iPhone 6+ in landscape behave differently. On an iPhone 6+ in portrait and "below" they will display as a modal.