# Force popover on iPhone with programmatically created UIPopoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create a new popover view as the anchor is not visible in Interface Builder during compile time.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319179/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-on-ios-8-iphone?lq=1), implementing the delegate method will force Popover on iPhone. (for reasons I don't understand)

It works great when on a segue as shown in the post. But I cannot get this to work in a non-segue way. (Popover does show up on iPad)

Please help!

The code is listed below:

```
func showOptions() {
    let contentView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PasteOption") as NewPasteOptionViewController
    contentView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    contentView.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200.0, 200.0)
    presentViewController(contentView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    var _popoverPresentationController = contentView.popoverPresentationController!
    _popoverPresentationController.delegate = self
    _popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any
    _popoverPresentationController.sourceView = view
    _popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = self.navigationItem.titleView!.frame
}
// this function below is never called.
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}
```

Additional Notes:

The presenting view controller is presented as a modal form sheet in another view, and encapsulated in a navigation controller.
The presented view controller is a custom table view controller.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems moving the line `presentViewController(contentView, animated: true, completion: nil)`
 to the end of the function would fix the issue.

Comment: You are correct. Curious that documentation did put that statement first (that particular piece of code does not have delegate set though)

Comment: Delegate setting should placed before presentViewController, what do you think?

Comment: How do you expect the presentation to succeed if you set the presentation controller after presentation?

Comment: @LeoNatan, what do you mean, the fix suggests setting the presentation controller before presentation.

Comment: Of course. After presentation has started, setting a presentation controller is meaningless.

Comment: The answer works well. It seems Apple's documentation is outdated. As it say, "Presenting a view controller with the popover style creates a popover presentation controller to manage the presentation process." "Configuring the popover presentation controller after calling presentViewController:animated:completion: might seem counter-intuitive but UIKit does not create a presentation controller until after you initiate a presentation."

Answer (score 1):

```
let contentView  = 
PLMainNavigationManager.sharedInstance.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PLSearchVCID") as! PLSearchVC
        contentView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        contentView.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400.0, 500.0)
        var _popoverPresentationController = contentView.popoverPresentationController!
        _popoverPresentationController.delegate = self
        _popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any
        _popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
       _popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(-30, -280, 320, 400)  
        PLMainNavigationManager.sharedInstance.navigationController?.presentViewController(contentView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```