# Real popover view programmatically on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipopovercontroller, popover

**EDIT:**
Added approach 3 (see comments below).

I want to create little popovers in my app but I can't use the storyboard since the anchor points for those popovers will be UIControls that the user creates.

I want to create *real* popovers like those described [here](http://richardallen.me/2014/11/28/popovers.html) (not fullscreen ones). It works great using the storyboard but in this case i need it to work without segues.

Also I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684865/force-popover-on-iphone-with-programmatically-created-uipopoverpresentationcontr) where the person tries to do something very similiar. I tried to use the solution from that post as below in *//approach 1*. In //approach 2 I tried the solution on [this](http://makeapppie.com/2014/08/30/the-swift-swift-tutorials-adding-modal-views-and-popovers/) site (even though it's for iPads only I think but I was out of ideas...).

```
// long press gesture: show additional control elements
func showLongPressMenu(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    // approach 1
    let newPopoverVC1 = UIViewController(nibName: "LinkAreaPopupView", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    newPopoverVC1.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    newPopoverVC1.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(137.0, 28.0)
    var newPopoverController = newPopoverVC1.popoverPresentationController!
    newPopoverController.delegate = self
    newPopoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    newPopoverController.sourceView = ???
    newPopoverController.sourceRect = ???
    presentViewController(newPopoverVC1, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // approach 2
    let newPopoverVC2 = UIViewController(nibName: "LinkAreaPopupView", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    newPopoverVC2.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    let popAnchorRect = self.frame
    let newPopover = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: newPopoverVC2)
    newPopover.presentPopoverFromRect(popAnchorRect, inView: ???, permittedArrowDirections: .Any, animated: true)

    // approach 3
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(137.0, 28.0)
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

    if let pres = vc.popoverPresentationController {
        pres.delegate = self
    }

    // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    self.superview.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let popView = LinkAreaPopupView()
    vc.view.addSubview(popView)
    popView.frame = vc.view.bounds
    popView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight

    if let pop = vc.popoverPresentationController {
        pop.sourceView = (self as UIView)
        pop.sourceRect = (self as UIView).bounds
    }
}
```

And the delegate function:

```
// don't allow to substitute the presentation style of popover controllers (to fullscreen for example)
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .None
}
```

The "LinkAreaPopupView" is a XIB file containing the menu I want to show.

My problem is that the class that has this code is a sublass of UIControl and will be created by the user. It doesn't know the "presentViewController()" function. The "presentPopoverFromRect()" function is not allowed to be called on iPhones (throws an error saying something about iPads). And obviously I'm missing some arguments too (the "???" parts).

Hope I didn't forget anything important. Thanks in advance

Comment: In iOS 8, real popovers on iPhone are legal, normal, and built in. Example code: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch09p477popoversOnPhone/PopoverOnPhone/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks for that @matt! A few questions still: what do I need to substitute   `let f = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("linkhelp", ofType: "html")
        let s = String(contentsOfFile: f!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        wv.loadHTMLString(s, baseURL: nil)`   with? I think this is where I load my XIB file instead? And how will I use this class in my project then?

Comment: sure but that's irrelevant. I'm just showing you that it works.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit blind here but still can't get it to work. I added your code as _//approach 3_ in my post above. The problem is that the UIControls can't call presentViewController(). Where do I have to do this? I tried calling it on self.superview instead but then it says "can't invoke [..] with an argument list of type [..].

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying I got it working. Together with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3MawJVxTgk) tutorial video which shows how to use views from XIB files and the comment from @matt I achieved to show popups from UIControls.

To instantiate my XIB file I created a UIView sublcass like this:

```
import UIKit

class LinkAreaPopupView: UIView {

    // outlets
    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var btnDeleteArea: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnLinkTo: UIButton!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LinkAreaPopupView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LinkAreaPopupView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }
}
```

Then in my UIControl sublcass in the function that shall create the popups I added this:

```
// long press gesture: show additional control elements
    func showLongPressMenu(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            // approach 3 - https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch09p477popoversOnPhone/PopoverOnPhone/ViewController.swift
            let vc = UIViewController()
            vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(137.0, 28.0)
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

            if let pres = vc.popoverPresentationController {
                pres.delegate = self
            }

            (self.delegate as! UIViewController).presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

            let popView = LinkAreaPopupView()
            vc.view.addSubview(popView)
            popView.frame = vc.view.bounds
            popView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight

            if let pop = vc.popoverPresentationController {
                pop.sourceView = (self as UIView)
                pop.sourceRect = (self as UIView).bounds
            }
        }
    }
```

The missing puzzle piece was to have the UIControl's delegate set to the UIViewController that lies underneath. And finally I had to cast `(self.delegate as! UIViewController)` because I implemented my own protocol to that delegate before and that's why I couldn't call `.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` on it.

Voila.