# UIPopViewController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, uipopovercontroller

I have an xib file with a .h and .m linked. In the xib there is a UIView with a textView. What I would like to do with that view is open it as a UIPopViewController when you click a button.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)thisButton:(id)sender
{
    popViewController *popVC = [[popViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"popViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popVC];

    [self.pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(220, 120) animated:YES];
    [self.pop presentPopoverFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame] inView:self.view
                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
}
```

It crashed with the following error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'
```

I don't understand the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIPopoverController only in iPad application.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    // for iPads
    // here you can use UIPopoverController   
} else
{
    // for iPhones
}
```

Comment: So there's no way of doing it on the iphone?

Comment: @MikeRally no, you should use other way for present view controllers on iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

`UIPopoverController` works on iPad only. In iOS 8 you can use [`UIPopoverPresentationController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html) for both iPhone and iPad, and there's a small trick to make it look like `UIPopoverController` which is explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25656733/1228075).

---

Here's the Objective-C version of the swift code you see in the link I provided.

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation SomeViewController

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender:(id) sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PopoverSegue"]) {
        UIViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
        controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 186);                
    }
}

// MARK: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate

-(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller 
{
    // Return no adaptive presentation style, use default presentation behaviour
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
@end
```

Comment: The link you gave me is described in swift

Comment: It's the same thing in Objective-C... Ok i'll translate it for you and update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Please let me know when you finish your update

Comment: I've included the obj-c equivalent.

Comment: It worked like a normal new viewController. Meaning it didn't pop over, it went to the next segue

Comment: It acted like a full sized viewController.

Comment: Try `UIModalPresentationPopover`. Although: "In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`."

Comment: I copy-pasted your code but it didn't work because you use a capital S in `Sender` in prepareForSegue, so that method never got called.

Comment: What would be the code equivalent? (Without Storyboard and Segues)

Comment: @Armin hey for me also its working as normal .. i want popover with background clear color to view previous viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

This must just work for you guys

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"popoverSegue"])

    {
        UIViewController *popUpControl=segue.destinationViewController;
        popUpControl.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationPopover;
        popUpControl.popoverPresentationController.delegate=self;
    }
}
-(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller
{
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

Comment: Could you also add some explanation?