# iOS9 popover always points to top-left corner of anchor

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

I'm using a storyboard segue that presents a view controller as popover. The seque has a custom `UIView` as its anchor. On pre-iOS9 the popover would correctly point to the centre-bottom of the custom `UIView` (presented below the UIView). On iOS9 it points to the top-left corner of the `UIView`.

I did try to trace all selector calls to the custom `UIView` to find out if there is anything I may need to implement in my custom `UIView` to provide the 'hotspot' for the popover but couldn't find anything

Any ideas..? Thanks

**Thanks to @Igor Camilo his reply - in case it's useful to some, this is how I fixed this in my code**:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

     UIPopoverPresentationController* possiblePopOver = segue.destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController;
     if (possiblePopOver != nil) {
         //
         // iOS9 -- ensure correct sourceRect
         //
         possiblePopOver.sourceRect = possiblePopOver.sourceView.bounds;
     }
    ...
 }
```

**Example:** 'Short' button triggers a popover, the popover points to the top-left corner of 'Sort' control

[image: Resulting popover]

[image: Segue settings]

Comment: You can't use `UIPopoverArrowDirection` constant? Everything else is deprecated.

Comment: Hi, the problem is not the direction -- that's defined correctly in the storyboard segue. The issue is the where the arrow points to.

Comment: So it's pointing to the origin and there's no way to adjust? Does the arrow go over the UIView or is it off of it?

Comment: Just added an example gif in my question above - you can see how the popover points to the top-left corner of the Sort button.

Comment: Are you using UIPopoverPresentationController or UIPopoverController? PresentationController has a a sourceRect and sourceView properties that should allow you to adjust the anchor point.

Comment: I'm using a storyboard segue which presents a popover on iPad. See second image with the settings. This works just fine on iOS8.

I suspect something changed in iOS9 and obtaining a sourceRect from the anchor must rely on a missing selector/property/whatever on my custom UIView (the Sort Button is a custom UIControl).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I just resolved it by setting sourceRect in prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "Popover Identifier"?:
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            segue.destinationViewController?.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = anchorView.bounds
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you get the `anchorView` ?

Comment: I updated Igor Camilo's answer using Objective-C. This should answer your question, @BuntyMadan

Comment: @BuntyMadan In my case, there was only one popover in my controller, so I just got the anchor view from my IBOutlets, but I believe you can grab it from `sender` or `popoverPresentationController?.sourceView`. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: I think this should be anchorView.bounds, rather than anchorView.frame. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30067716/220287

Answer (score 18):

Had the same issue but my app has a multitude of pop-over so I created a centralized function for the fix (but still had to use it on every view controller that had pop overs).

```
// Fix for IOS 9 pop-over arrow anchor bug
// ---------------------------------------
// - IOS9 points pop-over arrows on the top left corner of the anchor view
// - It seems that the popover controller's sourceRect is not being set
//   so, if it is empty  CGRect(0,0,0,0), we simply set it to the source view's bounds
//   which produces the same result as the IOS8 behaviour.
// - This method is to be called in the prepareForSegue method override of all
//   view controllers that use a PopOver segue
//
//   example use:
//
//          override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
//          {
//             fixIOS9PopOverAnchor(segue)   
//          }
//      
extension UIViewController
{
   func fixIOS9PopOverAnchor(segue:UIStoryboardSegue?)
   {
      guard #available(iOS 9.0, *) else { return }          
      if let popOver = segue?.destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController,
         let anchor  = popOver.sourceView
         where popOver.sourceRect == CGRect()      
            && segue!.sourceViewController === self 
      { popOver.sourceRect = anchor.bounds }   
   }       
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example of Igor Camilo's snippet in Objective-C.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // If the sender is a UIView, we might have to correct the sourceRect of
    // a potential popover being presented due to an iOS 9 bug. See:
    // https://openradar.appspot.com/22095792 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/32698841/368674
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:UIView.class]) {
        // Fetch the destination view controller
        UIViewController *destinationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        // If there is indeed a UIPopoverPresentationController involved
        if ([destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)]) {
            // Fetch the popover presentation controller
            UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverPresentationController =
            destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController;

            // Set the correct sourceRect given the sender's bounds
            popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = ((UIView *)sender).bounds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution is not suitable for tvOS, because there is no class `UIPopoverPresentationController`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my solution, inside `prepareForSegue`:

```
segue.destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(anchorView.frame.size.width/2, anchorView.frame.size.height, 0, 0)
```

This will move the pointer to the bottom middle of the anchor view

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem but now it works when I added this to my **PrepareForSegue** function. Given that my Segue ID contains string *Popover*

```
if ([[segue identifier] containsString:@"Popover"]) {
    [segue destinationViewController].popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = self.navigationItem.titleView.bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reference your popover `UIViewController` in your main `UIViewController` you can adjust the `sourceRect` property to offset the popover. For example, given popover `popoverVC` you can do something like so:

```
float xOffset = 10.0;
float yOffset = 5.0;
popoverVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGMakeRect(xOffset, yOffset, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set width and height anchor of your source rect (UIView or UIBarButtonItem ) and set it to active .Set it when you are initialising your UIView or UIBarButtonItem.

**UIBarButtonItem**

```
 [[youruibarbuttonitem.customView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:youruibarbuttonitem.customView.bounds.size.width] setActive:YES];
 [[youruibarbuttonitem.customView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:youruibarbuttonitem.customView.bounds.size.height] setActive:YES];
```

**UIView**

```
[[uiview.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:uiview.bounds.size.width] setActive:YES];
 [[uiview.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:uiview.bounds.size.height] setActive:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a more updated answer for Swift 3! Pardon all the casting

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "popSegue" {
            let popoverViewController = segue.destination
            popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
            segue.destination.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = ((sender as? UIButton)?.bounds)!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just to update to an actual example with working code for any UIView

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "PopoverSegueId"?:
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            segue.destination.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = (segue.destination.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView?.bounds)!
        }
    default:
        break
    }

}
```