# iOS, PopOverPresentationController issue, .xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, nib

I have a NavigationController, another controller was pushed on its stack: BNRDetailsViewController. Now, inside BNRDetailsViewController I am trying to show a popover window when pressing on a toolbar button, that would present me with UIImagePickerController (only on iPad devices). So, I tried to follow the following stackoverflow thread:

[UIPopoverPresentationController on iOS 8 iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319179/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-on-ios-8-iphone)

But no success. If I just use their code I get an error that says, that `pushing navigationController is not supported`. If I try to push the newly created `UIPopoverPresentationController` like this: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.imagePickerPopover animated:YES];` it crashes because `UIPopoverPresentationController` is not of type `UIViewController`, so, I guess, I can not just push it on the stack.

What would you suggest to do in this particular case?

Here is the code which I have right now that is triggered when the toolbar button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

// If the device have camera, take a picture, otherwise,
// just pick from photo library
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
} else {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}

imagePicker.delegate = self;

// Place image picker on the screen
//[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];

// Place image picker on the screen
// Check for iPad device before instantiating the popover controller
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // Create a new popover controller that will display the imagePicker
    _imagePickerPopover = [[UIPopoverPresentationController alloc] initWithPresentedViewController:imagePicker presentingViewController:self];

    imagePicker.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 200);
    _imagePickerPopover.delegate = self;
    _imagePickerPopover.sourceView = self.view;
    CGRect frame = [[sender valueForKey:@"view"] frame];
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 20;
    _imagePickerPopover.sourceRect = frame;
   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.imagePickerPopover animated:YES];
}
}
```

Comment: Basically you want to present a popover on iOS 8+.  See the example code in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28521583/558933 . The code presents a popover on both iPhone and iPad. If you want the popover to ONLY appear on iPad and NOT iPhone then return the appropriate `UIModalPresentationStyle` value.

Comment: Thank you!. However, I do not use storyboards, instead I have .xib file. So, I am still not sure what to do in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code, based on your code, that will get the popover to display on the iPad.

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    imagePicker.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 200);
    CGRect frame = [[sender valueForKey:@"view"] frame];
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 20;

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverController = 
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController;
    popoverController.sourceView = self.view;
    popoverController.sourceRect = frame;

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:imagePicker 
                               animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: OK, I got it. Just need to change one line: `popoverController.sourceView = self.view` to `popoverController.sourceView = self.toolbar` where `toolbar` was defined as a property inside the BNRDetailsViewController class: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar`

Comment: Just a note: preferredContSizre replaced popoverContentSize