# swift popovers without storyboard? XIB

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xib

I was wondering if anyone has figured out how to work with popovers in an iphone but not using storyboards?

[helpful but not quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319179/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-on-ios-8-iphone/25656733#25656733)

This was the closest one I was able to find, but the second answer which was the closest one, works with a navigation controller, and in my case my filterVC is not initialized with storyboard. Does anyone know of any other method to create a popover in iphone using xib? Currently I keep getting a nil error here:

```
popoverPresentationViewController!.sourceView = self.view;
```

ty!

Comment: See @bhnascar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521583/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-on-iphone-doesnt-produce-popover

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I have a question. Im kinda new to ios and something that confuses me, is: what are navigation controllers? I thought if I didn't use storyboards (which im not)-I use xibs- I didn't have to use NavigationControllers... or what exactly is the relationship between both?

Comment: Almost all UIKit applications use navigation controllers somewhere. Any application that has a top navigation bar and transition between view controllers by moving in new view controllers from the right side of the screen to left are using a navigation controller. They are one of a few kind container view controller that UIKit provides (UITabBarViewController, UISplitViewController being others). It is typically the job of container view controllers to hold, manage, and transition between view controllers. Try reading apple's "view controller catalog for iOS" section on nav controllers for mor