# Is it possible to show UIViewController as popover in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uipopover

I have created a `UIViewController` using `Interface Builder` is it possible to view the UIViewController as a popover of specified size.

The size of my `UIViewController` is default `600X600` since I am using size classes.

I have tried various answers available but none works for me.

Comment: No, you may try container layout.

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/38865881/6433023

Comment: You may need to depend a third party library. This may help you https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController

Answer (score 0):

For Showing Popover in Phone Just Make Category of UIPopoverController Code :

```
    //  UIPopoverController+iPhone.h
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

        @interface UIPopoverController (iPhone)
        + (BOOL)_popoversDisabled;
        @end
   //  UIPopoverController+iPhone.m


        #import "UIPopoverController+iPhone.h"

        @implementation UIPopoverController (iPhone)
        + (BOOL)_popoversDisabled {
            return NO;
        }
        @end
```

and just import this category where you required. and show popover as you show for iPAD.

```
-(IBAction)showPopOver:(id)sender {
TestPopOver *tstPop = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestPopOver"];
    popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:tstPop];
    popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(300.0, 300.0);
    [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame]
                                          inView:self.view
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                        animated:YES]; }
```