# UIPopoverController alternative on iphone devices

Tags: ios, swift, popover

I have been searching for almost 2 hours on how to implement UIPopoverController in swift language, at the end, i found out that this api are exclusive for iPad devices only.

How will i be able to make a drop down list on iPhone devices?

please someone help me, at lease with the name of the api so that i know what to search for

Comment: you can, but the HIG presents / offers different solutions for iPhone as the screen is not big enough for a popup; you may find the `UIPickerView` interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can you third party libraries for that:

- [FPPopover](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover.git)
- [WEPopover](https://cocoapods.org/pods/WEPopover)

or if you don't need iOS 7 support you can use iOS 8 new API which answered in this question

- [UIPopoverPresentationController on iOS 8 iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319179/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-on-ios-8-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

i depends on your needs. You can show UIPickerView, present an action sheet or segue to another VC and then go back - these are standard ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverPresentationController;

- (IBAction)showPopover:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *popoverViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NameViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popoverViewController];
    popoverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 200);
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    _popoverPresentationController = navigationController.popoverPresentationController;
    _popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
    _popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
    _popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = [sender frame];
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [_viewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```