# ios navigation bar 's back button not responding in popover

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm maintaining an old code based on xib files.
Everything worked fine, but recently, the back button of the navigation bar in a popover is no longer responding.
I changed from using a UIPopoverController to presenting the navigation controller with UIModalPresentationPopover style but nothing changed.
Here's what I'm doing:

```
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:instrusRootVC];
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
navController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400.0, 600.0);
navController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
navController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sender.frame;
navController.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
navController.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

where instrusRootVC is a table view controller initialized with initWithNibName

in instrusRootVC, I then call

```
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

where secondVC is a new table view controller initialized with initWithNibName

Everything works fine except that the back button of the navigation bar does not respond.

(If I call

```
 [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

somewhere in secondVC, it works fine.)

What am I doing wrong?

The full code is too long to go in comments, so here it is:

```
UINavigationController *navController;

if (APPTYPE == kTypeMultiInstruWithLevel) {

    InstrusNamesVC *instrusRootVC = [[InstrusNamesVC alloc]
            initWithTabInstruTypeNames: myPartitionInfos.partTabInstruNames
                WithTabAllInstrusModel: myPartitionInfos.partTabInstrus
             WithTabAllAnnPartByInstru: tabAnnotationsPartitionByInstru];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:instrusRootVC];

} else {

    if ([myPartitionInfos.partTabInstrus count] > 1)
    {
        InstrusViewController *instrusRootVC = [[InstrusViewController alloc] initWithTabInstrusModel:myPartitionInfos.partTabInstrus WithTabAnnPartByInstru:tabAnnotationsPartitionByInstru];
        navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:instrusRootVC];

    }
    // We only have one instru, we skip the instru selection step
    else
    {
        InstruPartitionVersionsVC *instrusRootVC = [[InstruPartitionVersionsVC alloc] initWithIndexInstru: 0
                WithTabAnnPartByInstru: tabAnnotationsPartitionByInstru];

        navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:instrusRootVC];
    }
}

navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
navController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(400.0, 600.0);
navController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
navController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sender.frame;
navController.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
navController.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;

navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
navController.navigationBar.tintColor = SCROLL_COLOR_MMR;
if(APPDESIGN== kDesignPinkPanther){
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:138/255.0 blue:177/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    navController.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:138/255.0 blue:177/255.0 alpha:1.0];
} else if (APPDESIGN== kDesignCarmen){
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:193/255.0 green:38/255.0 blue:67/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    navController.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:193/255.0 green:38/255.0 blue:67/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}  else {
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = BROWN_COLOR_MMR;
    navController.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = BROWN_COLOR_MMR;
}

[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in instruViewController for example the code is as follow:

```
- (id)initWithTabInstrusModel: (NSArray *)pTabInstru
   WithTabAnnPartByInstru: (NSArray *)pTabAnn
 {
self = [super initWithNibName:@"InstrusViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

if (self != nil)
{
    tabInstrusModel = pTabInstru;
    tabAnnPartByInstru = pTabAnn;
}

return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// init properties
self.tabInstrusItems = [NSMutableArray array];

// Init tabInstruItems
for (int i = 0; i < [tabInstrusModel count]; i++)
{
    InstrumentPartitionModel *instruTMP = [tabInstrusModel objectAtIndex:i];
    [tabInstrusItems addObject:locStr(instruTMP.instruName)];
}

// let selection done before
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// set background custom
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_popup.png"];
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:backgroundImage];
backgroundImageView.frame = self.tableView.frame;
self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundImageView;

self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

self.tableView.rowHeight = 50.0;

// Set navigation bar title
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[label formatAsTitlePopover:@""];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:label];
```

then I experimented with 
1) not specifying anything for self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem
2) using this:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self.navigationController  action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:)];
```

3) using this:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil  action:nil];
```

But this does not change anything (except that when I do not specify anything, the back button display "back"): the button remains inactive.
I even tried to put

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
```

without any success.

Then the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is as follows:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[(CustomUITableView *)tableView updateCellSelect : indexPath];

InstruPartitionVersionsVC *versionsVC = [[InstruPartitionVersionsVC alloc]
        initWithIndexInstru: indexPath.row
     WithTabAnnPartByInstru: tabAnnPartByInstru];

// In case of MultiInstruWithLevel, tabAnnPartByInstru only contains partitions for the selected instr type:
if (APPTYPE == kTypeMultiInstruWithLevel) {
    NSArray * tabAnnPartTMP = [tabAnnPartByInstru objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    AnnotationsPartitionModel *annPartTMP = [tabAnnPartTMP objectAtIndex:0];
    versionsVC.indexGlobal = annPartTMP.annPartInstruDisplay;
} else {
    versionsVC.indexGlobal = indexPath.row;
}

// Display new Controller
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:versionsVC animated:YES];
 }
```

And so on for the next TableViewControllers...

I checked that all table views controller put on the stack have the same size.

Now, I really do not know what I could check....

Comment: Show me your full code for bringing the solution.

Comment: Is the bar button visible?

Comment: kindly go through this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319179/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-on-ios-8-iphone

Comment: Yes, the back button is visible but inactive. Here is the full code:

Comment: I have edited my first post with the full code and an explanation of what I tried.

Comment: It seems to me that I'm doing what is described in the link you gave me. The app is intended to run only on iPad, so I do not have to worry about how it runs on iPhone.

Comment: It would be great if you could help me !

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand why the default back button suddenly stopped responding but I found a turn-around using the left bar button that works fine and I'd like to share it.

What I did is adding the following lines in the viewDidLoad method of each viewController intended to be pushed by the navigation controller presented as a popOver:

```
 if (self != [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0])
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_back_popover.png"]
                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(leftBtnPressed:)];
}
```

where leftBtnPressed is as follows:

```
-(IBAction)leftBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```