# What is the iOS equivalent of the android three dot menu icon?

Tags: ios, user-interface, user-experience

Android uses three dots (pictured) to show that there are more menu items available. What is the iOS equivalent of this icon?

[image: Android three dots menu]

[image]

Comment: For the three dots of the overflow ActionBar menu, you could consider using a [Popover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47377027/3681880).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **no clear equivalent**, the closest I can think of are the horizontal three dots inside a `UITabBarItem` when there is no space to show the options:

[image: tab bar - more icon]

That being said, contextual menus are not common in iOS apps and there is **no default UI item** for them.

Comment: Don't want this to be the right answer, but it is!!

Answer (score 11):

It's : **ellipsis**

and you can use it like this :

```
Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
```

Comment: May also rotate it by using the rotationEffect modifier.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [more system icon](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarsystemitem/1617069-more) from Apple

See all [system icons here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/system-icons/)

Answer (score 1):

I myself use the "square.and.arrow.up" system icon as my equivalent. Though the Android icon isn't so terrible you could implement it yourself.

Additionally a bottom action sheet is a great equivalent for Android's Contextual Menu.

---

SwiftUI Implementation of action sheet

```
.actionSheet(isPresented: $showingActionSheet) {
    ActionSheet(title: Text("Change background"), message: Text("Select a new color"), buttons: [
        .default(Text("Red")) { self.backgroundColor = .red },
        .default(Text("Green")) { self.backgroundColor = .green },
        .default(Text("Blue")) { self.backgroundColor = .blue },
        .cancel()
    ])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, tapping on the 3 dots shows a new screen with details from the item you've selected? If that's it then on iOS the equivalent is a chevron (`>`) symbol. It tells you that tapping the entry takes you to a detail screen.

Comment: The functionality brings up a pop up once clicked where you can choose a menu item which will take you somewhere else. I think the chevron is to navigate to the next page in the journey

Comment: I have edited my original post to include image showing what i mean

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like the Apple [share icon](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR4mmKHo3OlJZ0MoUmZRZXIefOlK5TC7NDLkSOypt7wvCbr4xynrfX6rew) is the closest thing. Tapping on that brings up a menu of different options for printing, copying to the clipboard, saving to your photo library, sharing via email/text/facebook/etc (options vary based on context.) However I haven't seen that used in a list item like you show for Android.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 14 Apple introduced Pull-Down menus. It should be the closest thing to Android overflow menus. For example, you can add a "more" bar button item to your navigation bar and attach a menu to it.

You can find details about it here: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pull-down-menus/