# Present a popover from an arbitrary anchor point in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, popover

I know how to present a popover from a bar button item as is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32295907/3681880) (for both iPhone and iPad).

[image]

I would like to add a popover for an arbitrary anchor point. The other SO answers that I saw were for bar button items or in Objective-C.

I just learned how to do this, so I am adding my own answer below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Updated for Swift 3*

In the storyboard, add a view controller that you would like to be the popover. Set the Storyboard ID to be "popoverId".

[image]

Also add a button to your main view controller and hook up the IBAction to the following code.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func buttonTap(sender: UIButton) {

        // get a reference to the view controller for the popover
        let popController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popoverId")

        // set the presentation style
        popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

        // set up the popover presentation controller
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender // button
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds

        // present the popover
        self.present(popController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method
    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        // Force popover style
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
    }
}
```

Setting the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` is what allows you to choose an arbitrary point to display the popover.

That's it. Now it should like something like this when the button is tapped.

[image]

Thanks to [this article](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-create-popovers-in-ios-9/) for help.

Comment: `popController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender`

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how to make a smaller view controller like what you showed?

Comment: @PeterLai, It has been a while since I have worked on this. I don't remember what I did right now. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663002/how-to-present-a-view-controller-with-smaller-size

Answer (score 10):

Solution for Swift 3.1 :

Add to your ViewController *UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate* delegate :

```
class OriginalViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
```

Add a button to your ViewController and on tap on your button, call this code :

```
    let controller = MyPopViewController()
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
    let popController = controller.popoverPresentationController
    popController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
    popController?.delegate = self
    popController?.sourceRect = (self.myButton?.bounds)!
    popController?.sourceView =  self.myButton
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

Update to func syntax above:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentatinStyle { 
    return .none 
}
```

For some reason the old syntax is still allowed but is not active and will not implement popup or anchor correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You can add height and width for the popup:

```
popController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
```