# How to present a view controller with smaller size

Tags: ios, swift, size, frame, presentviewcontroller

I want presented view controller vc2 in smaller size than the screen, how to do that in Swift 3 ?? Thanks for help.
This is my code:

```
@IBAction func leftButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Controller2") as! ViewController2
    vc2.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext

    present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You want the left over space to be clickable so it overlays current context and allows clicking things that are below ?
Or you want to only visually make it smaller but it should still take whole screen in terms of interactions ?

Comment: I want to only visually smaller and take whole screen in terms of interaction. But top part of parent screen can be seen.

Comment: I made a Github repo [BonsaiController](https://github.com/rishi420/Bonsai) just for that.

Answer (score 6):

Try this..

```
@IBAction func leftButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Controller2") as! ViewController
    vc2.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
    vc2.definesPresentationContext = true
    vc2.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    self.present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // Make sure your vc2 background color is transparent
    vc2.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much.  I also try to add a UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate method:

Comment: I add a method:    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return SmallViewController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)
    }
and a class: class SmallViewController : UIPresentationController {
    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: containerView!.bounds.width, height: containerView!.bounds.height/2)
    }
}
but not worked well.  V2 is a table, it will scroll very slow.

Comment: @Peterq2001if you think this is the right answer, please mark it

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a container view to display the smaller view controller. Here is a great tutorial on container views: https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/

Hope this was helpful :)