# MVVMCross & Xamarin.ios - Anchoring a menu to the previous Views Button

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using MVVMCross along with Xamarin in my iOS app. I want to implement a popover menu that is activated when a button is clicked (see image below). I have a homeview for my table and menuview for the menu (with an associated MvxViewModel for each). All standard stuff.

What I am struggling with is how to pass the anchor point (i.e. the top right button) from the homeview to the menuview.

Any pointers in the right direction would be great. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you developed the UI like your reference Image in iOS? This may link may help if you have not seen early https://stackoverflow.com/a/32295907/8892050.

Comment: Hi @Ranjit, It is. I actually did get some valuable info from that question earlier when developing the concept.  The issue I have now is that I actually want to bind the menu view to it's only ViewModel using mvvmcross. I've managed to get it working a built in property for popovers and now just need to create my own for menu. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading and re-reading the commit comments for the feature at MvvmCross I realised I needed to add the following code to the home view:

```
var provider = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxPopoverPresentationSourceProvider>();
provider.SourceView = CategoryLabel;
```

The above anchors the popover to the Category Label.